# Issue Implementing UIPageViewController

Tags: swift

I am trying to implement to scroll between two view controllers, one to be a message page, and the other view controller to be a camera page, similar to snapchat app. If I didn't make myself understood I attached an image with the app that has exactly the same implementation as I'm trying to do, it has 5 views which you can scroll between them. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmg4Q.jpg)
Now I have tried it to implement in multiple ways. One of them is with UIPageViewController, snippet of my code:

```
   class ViewController:  UIViewController , UIPageViewControllerDelegate
  {


var chatVC = one()
var cameraVC= two()
var array  = [UIViewController]()
var arr = [UIViewController]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    self.array = [chatVC,cameraVC]
    self.arr = [chatVC]
  
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
        self.presentPageVC()
        
    })
   
        
    
  
    
    
    
}

func presentPageVC(){
    var vc = UIPageViewController.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal , options: nil)
    vc.delegate = self
    vc.dataSource = self
    vc.setViewControllers(self.arr, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}











func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let index = self.array.firstIndex(of: viewController),index>0 else {return nil}
     
    let beforeIndex = index - 1
    
    
    return self.array[beforeIndex]
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let index = self.array.firstIndex(of: viewController), index < (self.array.count-1) else {
        return nil
    }
    var indexAfter = index + 1
    
    return self.array[indexAfter]
    
}
```

With this implementation I have one problem as I try to scroll after the last page on the cameraVC, on the right it appears the view behind it. How could I turnOff scrolling when there is no other page after or before.
As well, Im new to software development, if somebody has a better idea for implementing it, please let me know. I get stuck at trying to implementing with UICollectionView because I don't know how to convert a UIViewController to a cell, and how to change depending on it on the delegate. As well when trying to add via UIScrollView, I don't understand how I could a UIViewController subview to the UIScrollview, because it accepts only UIView.
Thank you in advance for the help,

Comment: You haven't made the basic setup.  Your `PageViewController` requires `setViewControllers(_:direction:animated:completion:)`.

Comment: @ElTomato double check it is there

Comment: What's this?  vc.setViewControllers(self.arr, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)  And var chatVC = one()?

Comment: @ElTomato is the chatViewController added, do you know a better implementation for a look alike snapchat photos that I provided, or you know how to deactivate left scrolling on the first page, and deactivate right scrolling on the last page?

Comment: How do you know that they are using `UIPageController`?  It looks to me that they have a subclass of `UIViewController` to create their own tab view.

Comment: @ElTomato, could you please read one more time the whole code. Check the presentPageVC method please.

Comment: "How could I turnOff scrolling when there is no other page after or before."  What is your definition of scrolling?

Comment: "how I could a UIViewController subview to the UIScrollview"  What is the verb in this sentence?

Comment: @ElTomato thank you already solved, I meant that when you have two views in a scrollview and lets say that you are on the first view and you try scrolling as to appear the view before, in the case it doesn't exist it will show the view that it is under the UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody who wants the UIScrollView to don't show the viewUnder when scrolling there are no existent views to scroll.

```
scrollView.showsLargeContentViewer = false
```